# Trying to split up data by [70:30] ratio

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

The exact question that I'm trying to solve is:

"Then split the feature X and the target y into training and test sets with
the ratio of 70:30. Print the size of the training and test set."

and this is the code that I have so far:

```
X = df['bmi']
y = df['charges']
trainX, testX, trainY, testY=train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.7)

print("trainX:", trainX.shape,"testX:",  testX.shape, "trainY:", trainY.shape, "testY:", testY.shape)
print()
```

Is this the correct way to answer the question?

Comment: "... into training and test sets with the ratio of 70:30".... seems to me like the training set needs to be 0.7, and the test set needs to be 0.3.   More info here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/train-test-split-for-evaluating-machine-learning-algorithms/      Looks to me that you have it the other way around.

Comment: It should be `test_size=.3` or `train_size=.7`. Please refer [train_test_split documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your training data should be the 70% then in your code you should use test_size = 0.3

```
trainX, testX, trainY, testY=train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.3)
```